# How to import a non-spatial Table into QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Can I import tabular data in Qgis, without any information about X and Y only the table? 
I need to join them after importing them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can import a csv file and make a join by attributes with the [mmqgis](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/) plugin.

*Extension > Mmqgis > Attributes join from CSV file*

Answer (score 10):

Sure thing.  Just load it via the Add Vector Layer button.  It's not really a vector layer I know but that's just how it's coded at the moment.

Answer (score 8):

Since QGIS 2.6 (at least since mmqgis tools were imported in the main menu) this is done by the menu

*Layer > Add layer > Add Delimited Text Layer*

Browse to your file in the File name field

Under Geometry Definition, choose "No geometry (attribute only table)"

Relevant section in docs: [Importing a delimited text file](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#importing-a-delimited-text-file)